# SuiteCRM/SugarCRM: How to show a value in accounts list view?

Tags: listview, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to show a value in list view of Accounts module, how can I achieve this?

To do this I have added a field/column in Accounts module list view, and I got the desired value, now want to show the value in the newly added column in list view.
For the reference, I have attached the image also, in the image "Campaign date is the new column which I have added, and in this column I want to show the date which I calculated already".

[image: image of the newly added field, in list view]

Comment: Is the value set on each of the two records? If it's calculated, have you saved it? What is the calculated field code?

Answer (score 0):

Use studio. Then run a repair and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The list view is showing your column, so you are done with the studio changes.

Now, you need to populate that field with information, you have a few options

1. if the field is part of accounts, Add the column to the Accounts  "edit view " and then just edit the field.
2. if the field is calculated, you can do it using a Logic Hook or Scheduler Job.
3. Updated it using a database query

Answer (score 0):

If the field "Campaign date" is a calculated field and you have he value calulated only for few records then you can run a mass update which will update the calculated field in all records. Hope it helps!